# Custom post format for custom post type : Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom post type floors and I need to make dropdown with several templates (2templates) like standard floors and garage floors. In posts I can make like several .php files with  this code in head `/* Template Name Posts: # article post  */` and dropdown will automatically creating in backend. But in Custom post type I add in the head

```
/* Single Post Template: Floors
*/
```

this code and no dropdown creating, no reaction. How can I do the same with custom post types, and in what format must be .php file. Now I have one single-floors.php and need another like garage-singlefloors.php. Will be happy for every answer!

Comment: Custom post types use the `single-post_type.php` file as their template in which `post_type` is what you defined for the custom post type. One thing you could try is adding specific categories to your custom posts and then in the `single-post_type.php` template, add conditional logic to display different elements depending on the category.

Comment: mcon , thanks.  I had created template parts and loaded radio buttons on backend with 2 options but now I don't know how to use this metabox in my php file. maybe do you know how to insert my tepl options in the radio options? I've used this tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522380/how-to-set-radio-buttons-in-custom-meta-box-checked

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in post formats for custom post types using `add_post_type_support( $post_type, $supports )`.

See [related documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support) in the Codex.